# When is Game Center Welcome Back banner firing?

Tags: ios, game-center

My iOS game is using Game Center.

I am authenticating via the following code:

```
GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController* viewController, NSError* error) {
    if (viewController != nil) { [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil]; }
    else {            
        if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
            // code for Game Center enabled
            [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:getLeaderboardIdentifier]; }
        else {
            // code for Game Center disabled
        }
    } // viewController was nil
}; // localPlayer.authenticateHandler
```

It all works well, but when the game has been in the background for some time and gets restarted, the annoying "welcome back banner" is displayed even though I am not calling the previous code as I have checked that ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == YES)...

Is there a way to know if this banner is going to appear that I could use in applicationWillEnterForeground?

At worse, is there a known background delay that triggers it?

In this case I would slightly delay resuming into the game for a better UX...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there does not seem to be a way to know in advance for sure if the "Welcome Back" banner is going to be displayed when localPlayer is already authenticated, I will for now stick with the background delay trick.

I have done a dichotomic test by playing the game, leaving the App in the background and returning to the App after delay D.

It seems that the "Welcome Back" banner does not appear if D < 8 minutes and does if D is greater. If that may help others in improving their user experience...

In my case, if D >= 8 minutes when applicationWillEnterForeground, I disable the resume game button for 2.5 seconds. Most of the time, the "Welcome Back" banner appears during that lapse and doesn't bother the user while a tough game is restarting.